# how to select cells in worksheet based on their addresses

Tags: vba, excel

if i have an 1 dimensional array and each element of the array carry  cell address.

Now I want to select those cells  in a worksheet of carrying these addresses
 Hint the selection should be multi selection of all addresses
Something like .select property
 In order to do use the selection for further operations like selection.copy and so on

Comment: [Avoid Select and Activate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/1188513)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would loop through the array and use Union:

```
Sub foo()
Dim rng As Range
Dim arr()
Dim i As Long

arr = Array("$A$1", "$CD$5", "$F$4", "$H$8")

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    If i = LBound(arr) Then
        Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(arr(i))
    Else
        Set rng = Union(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(arr(i)), rng)
    End If
Next i

Debug.Print rng.Address(0, 0, xlA1, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: If I add this line to the code  rng.select    will it select those cells in the sheet?

Comment: Yes, but it is not recommended that one uses select, it slows down the code.  Just do what you want with the range directly.

Answer (score 3):

If your array is in a variable like "arr", then you could use something like this;

```
dim rng as Range

set rng=Sheet1.Range(Join(arr,","))
```

Now ***rng*** has will have your address in your array. But bear in mind, some operations such as copy may not be possible on such multiple selections. But could certainly do some formatting

Comment: Can you provide more information. Did you get some sort of error and what did you intend to do with the range.